# Ruby net::imap adding color categorys to emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap

I am reading in a lot of emails every day using net::imap
https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/net/imap/rdoc/Net/IMAP.html

I cannot seem to find a way to add a colored category to a message.

For example

```
imap.search(["ON","26-APR-2021"]).each do |message_id|
# my code...
# at the end of the code
  message_id.AddCatagory(blue)...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method name would be add_category in well-written ruby. But that doesn't exist, because colours aren't a concept in IMAP. Flags do exist, and I know some clients use colours to represent flags... so the code you're probably looking for is something along the lines of

imap.uid_store(uids, "+flags", [:Blue])

You have to define Blue, of course. Or Important, Flagged or something. Flagged is used by many clients for vaguely important messages.

Comment: I dont have a reference for this, but I believe either MS or Apple mail uses three separate flags for the three primary colors, and uses combinations of them for secondary colors.  The best way to find out is to set some colors on your email and fetch the flags and see what changed.  This is both client and potentially mail provider specific.  (Exchange may not expose it at all to IMAP)